# Bug When I delete a row from tableview Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift4

I'm trying to use `editActionForRowAt` to delete rows from table view, but when I try to delete the element is deleted from the database but the application crashes and this error come:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Here is my view controller code:

```
class ShowTargetVC: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
let Images = ["airplane","ambulance","analytics","backpack","ball","book","birthday-cake","brainstorm","business-partnership","car","coffee","commission","contract","drama","emergency","food","friends","grandparents","growth","home","hotel","newlyweds","sexual-harassment","taxi","workspace"]


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var transactions = [Transaction]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    API.getTransaction(username: "1",type : "target") { (error :Error?, transactions : [Transaction]?) in
        if let transactions = transactions {

            self.transactions = transactions
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return transactions.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "target")

    let contentView = cell?.viewWithTag(1)
    let image = contentView?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
    let name = cell!.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
    let money = cell!.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
    image.image = UIImage (named: Images[indexPath.item])
   name.text = transactions[indexPath.item].name
    //print(transactions[indexPath.item].name)
    money.text = String(transactions[indexPath.item].trMoney)
    return cell!
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let deletAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { (UITableViewRowAction
        , IndexPath) in
        API.deleteTransaction(id: String(self.transactions[indexPath.item].id))
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath], with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }

return [deletAction]

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delete your data from your local array as well.

Replace your method with below one

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

let deletAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { (UITableViewRowAction
    , IndexPath) in
    API.deleteTransaction(id: String(self.transactions[indexPath.item].id))
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
       // ** add below line. ** 
        self.transactions.remove(at: IndexPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath], with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }

return [deletAction]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the item also from the data source array and `beginUpdates / endUpdates` is pointless in this case.

And it's highly recommended to name the parameters in the action closure `lowercased`.
A variable `IndexPath` could clash with the struct `IndexPath`.

```
let deletAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { (_, indexPath) in
    API.deleteTransaction(id: String(self.transactions[indexPath.row].id))
    self.transactions.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```